# What is CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE?

Tags: php, curl

What exactly does `FORBID_REUSE` do in libcurl, specifically in the PHP implementation of CURL if there is any difference.  I found documentation for it here: http://scriptbasic.com/html/texi/mod_curl/mod_curl_3.46.html, but that really doesn't help too much.  It just says "if you don't know what you're doing, don't use it."

Well, I'd like to know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> TRUE to force the connection to explicitly close when it has finished processing, and not be pooled for reuse.

Usually, multiple HTTP requests to the same web server are sent sequentially on the same TCP connection. This option disables that and makes curl open a new TCP connection for each HTTP request, presumably to deal with broken HTTP servers.

Comment: Why would you want to force it to open a new connection with HTTP requests?

Comment: @tandu You'd use `FORBID_REUSE` if you suspect the remote server has a broken HTTP continuation implementation and doesn't answer (or run into an error halfway into the answer) the second request on a TCP connection. There could also be a very old proxy that bulks on multiple requests. Or you could want to do a performance test of curl's connection setup. All these scenarios are esoteric, but that's why it's an *option* and not standard.

Comment: I think it's impact performance and depend on your needs. If you CURL lot of different servers, you should set it to false (so there is no cache used). Question is: "is it will survive to the process exit?"

Comment: @ThomasDecaux No, it has no effect on the next time you start curl. If you want the option again, just set it again.

Comment: @phihag Thanks, so the "cache" is only for the current process who use curl.

Answer (score 1):

> TRUE to force the connection to explicitly close when it has finished processing, and not be pooled for reuse.

In my experience -- I've never had to use it. It's a step to preventing caching.

Comment: Source for that quote? ;P

Comment: I don't see how this relates to caching... This is related to the TCP connection, and whether an existing one can be reused, or a new one should be created everytime. It does not seem to have anything to do with content caching.